# is it possible to write machine learning algorithm in octave or python for application created in android

Tags: python, neural-network, java

We planned to create an Android app which predicts the present student in class through face detection by camera in the class, my job is to write algorithm for face detection and the problem is I can do it for octave and Python but never did for Java or other programming language.

Can I use the octave or Python script for Android app, is there any possible ways to connect the dots between Android app and Python/octave script?

Comment: Try to use tensorflow which can be employed in android